# Scala Play 2.5 with Slick 3 and Spec2

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, slick

I have a play application using Slick that I want to test using Spec2, but I keep getting the error `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already`. I have tried to shut down the database connection by using

```
val mockApp = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
val db = mockApp.injector.instanceOf[DBApi].database("default")

...

override def afterAll = {
  db.getConnection().close()
  db.shutdown()
}
```

But the error persists. The Slick configuration is

```
slick.dbs.default.driver="slick.driver.PostgresDriver$"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url="jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/hygge_db"
slick.dbs.default.db.user="*****"
slick.dbs.default.db.password="*****"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getConnection` of DbApi either gets connection from underlying data-source's (`JdbcDataSource` I presume) pool or creates a new one. I see no pool specified in your configuration, so I think it always creates a new one for you. So if you didn't close connection inside the test - `getConnection` won't help - it will just try to create a new one or take random connection from pool (if pooling is enabled).

So the solution is to either configure connection pooling:

> When using a connection pool (which is always recommended in
>   production environments) the minimum size of the connection pool
>   should also be set to at least the same size. The maximum size of the
>   connection pool can be set much higher than in a blocking application.
>   Any connections beyond the size of the thread pool will only be used
>   when other connections are required to keep a database session open
>   (e.g. while waiting for the result from an asynchronous computation in
>   the middle of a transaction) but are not actively doing any work on
>   the database.

so you can just set maximum available connections number in your config:

```
connectionPool = 5
```

Or you can share same connection (you'll probably have to ensure sequentiality then):

```
object SharedConnectionForAllTests{ 
  val connection = db.getConnection()
  def close() = connection.close()
}
```

It's better to inject it with Spring/Guice of course, so you could conviniently manage connection's lifecycle.

Comment: Adding a shared connection object did the trick, slick manages your connection pool for you, but I was creating multiple guice injectors, and each were creating their own connection pool, and it overwhelmed the db. Thanks!